# Next.js (v13) | rewrite and redirect does not work in the Middleware. -> when reques from page (run) but from api (not work)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, middleware

I am coding with Next.js v13.

**You can find the codes I wrote by looking towards the end of this text.**

working principle:
1- I'm throwing requests and values to the service that makes a fetch with a client side component.

2- The service receives the incoming request and sends it to the API.

3- the request goes through a "middleware.js" before going to the api

3.1 - reaching api if middleware allows request

3.2 - If the middleware does not allow the request, it performs the necessary actions and redirects to a different page with NextResponse.redirect(...).

my problem:
I trigger my middleware when I go to a normal page and this NextResponse.redirect(...) operation works fine.
HOWEVER!
Unfortunately, when I send a request to an api, it doesn't work.

Fetch operation in api requests returns data as res.json().

and I'm returning a redirect from the middleware with NextResponse.redirect(...) only.

I think the question is related to this, but I would appreciate it if you could examine it and let me know.

please fallow the steps.
**page.js > service(postAPI) > middleware > API**

**page.js (runing when onSubmit)**

```
await postAPI("/auth/sendVerifyEmail", values).then((data) => {
          if(!data){
            toast.error("Bir hata oluştu. Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyiniz.");
            setIsloading(false);
            return;
          }
          else{
            if (data.status === "success") {
              setIsAccessing(true);
              setIsloading(false);
              toast.success(data.message + " Lütfen Bekleyin, yönlendiriliyorsunuz...");
            
              //Bilgi verir ve 5 saniye sonra login sayfasına yönlendirir.
              const timeOut = setInterval(() => {
                if(data.role){
                  setIsloading(false);
                  router.push(`/auth/login/${data.role.toLowerCase()}`);
                }
                else{
                  setIsloading(false);
                  router.push(`/`);
                }
                
                
                clearInterval(timeOut);
              }, 4000);
              
            } else {
              toast.error(data.message);
              setIsloading(false);
            }
          }
        });
```

**service(postAPI) running when onsubmit from page.js**

```
export async function postAPI(URL, body = "", method="POST", headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}){
try {
    const data = await fetch (`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + URL}`,{
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
        
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
    return data;

} catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`API request failed: ${error.message}`);
}
```

}

**middleware.js (running middleware when service post to api)**

```
  export async function middleware(req, res, next) {
  
  const { pathname } = new URL(req.url) || new URL(req.nextUrl);
  console.log("pathname : " + pathname)
  console.log(data);
  if (
    // istek gidecek sayfaları burada belirledik. eğer bu sayfalara istek giderse kontrol edilecek
    (pathname.startsWith('/api/auth/verifyEmail')) && (req.method === "POST")
  ) {
        //triggered on api request but not working!
        //triggers and works for the page!
        return NextResponse.rewrite(targetUrl);

        }
    else{
        // kullanıcı limiti aşmadı ise isteği gönderir.
        return NextResponse.next();
    }
  }
}
```

**API**
**API ONLY : OPERATES WITH VALUES SENT TO API AND RETURNS OBJECTS BACK**

like this: `return res.status(401).json({status: "error", error: error?.message, message: error?.message});`

In these structures, I cannot use rewrite or redirect structures in api requests.

there is only one error i got back room:
***"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"***

I think it's because I returned it as **res.json** in the service section but when I deleted it **my problem still wasn't resolved...**

Comment: You received an HTML as response and you assumed it's a JSON

Comment: @LajosArpad 

Congratulations, as you say, the error is right there. thanks. I have completed my process by using the incoming HTML object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @LajosArpad said, I encountered this problem because I did not use the structure I returned as response correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).